# How do you convert a string into a char in c++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure out how I could convert a string into a char, I keep seeing posts online to use strcpy but I can't figure out how to use it. Can someone show an example?

Comment: A string is a sequence of multiple chars. How do you expect to put it into a single char? It's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: If you'd like to get a C-style `const char *` from your `std::string`, you can do it like this:  `const char * myPtr = myString.c_str();`  (note that the pointed-to-characters are still owned by the `std::string` object and will likely become invalidated if you modify the `std::string`, so make a copy of them if you need to)

Answer (score 0):

How about?:

```
std::string foo = "Your string";
const char* as_char = foo.c_str();
```

Comment: The pointer returned may be rendered invalid by further calls to the object member functions, so make sure you make a copy of it if you need to.